# Check if point is inside ellipsoid - matrix form.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I computed a minimum volume ellipsoid that bounds a set of.points and it is represented in the center form as:

$ (x-c)^T * A * (x-c) = 1$

I compute the A and C. To get the parameters of the ellipse I use the single value decomposition as :

$ U, D, V = svd (A)$

Now I wanted to check if a random point $P$ is within the ellipse. Is there a linear algebra way to do this without having to convet to the algebraic form of the ellipse?

Comment: If you have the ellipse in matrix form already, can't you just plug the point P into it and check the sign? Maybe I misunderstand what you mean by "matrix form", you should elaborate.

Comment: This is the background of the ellipsoid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016898/port-matlab-bounding-ellipsoid-code-to-python - I hope it helps a little. Meanwhile I'll improve the question with diagrams.

Comment: @Rahul updated the question.

Comment: If $x$ is in the surface of the ellipse then $(x-c)^TA(x-c)$ equals $1$. If it is less than $1$, then $x$ is inside the ellipse.